# write a c function that generates one random number, or a pair of random numbers, or a triplet of random numbers given the particular ranges

Tags: c, function, random, conceptual

i have to generate random numbers for 3 different cases.
i. 1 dice
ii. a pair of dice
iii. 3 dices
my questions:
1. please suggest me sm good logic to generate random numbers for all the 3 cases.
2. does the logic change when i consider the cses of 2 dices, rather than 1?
3.how much of an effect does the range in which we have to genrate a random number affect the logic of the random function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the range is small enough, you shouldn't have problems in using the usual modulo method

```
int GetRandomInt(int Min, int Max)
{
    return (rand()%(Max-Min+1))+Min;
}
```

(where `Min` a `Max` specify a closed interval, [`Min`, `Max`])

and calling it once for each dice roll. Don't forget to call `srand(time(NULL))` at the start of the application (at the start *only*, not each time you want to get a random number) to seed the random number generator.

If the range starts to be bigger, you may have to face two problems:

First, the range of `rand()` obviously isn't [0, +∞), instead it's [0, `RAND_MAX`], where `RAND_MAX` is a `#define` guaranteed to be at least 32767. If your range (`Max-Min`) spans over `RAND_MAX`, then, with this method, you'll have some numbers that will have a zero probability of being returned.

This is more subtle: suppose that `RAND_MAX` is bigger than your range, but not *that* bigger, let's say that `RAND_MAX==1.5*/(Max-Min)`.
In this case, the distribution of results won't be uniform: `rand()` returns you an integer in the range [0, `RAND_MAX`] (and each integer in this range should be equiprobable), but you are taking the rest of the division with `(Max-Min)`. This means that the numbers in the first half of your required range have twice the probability of being returned than the others: they can actually come from the first *and* the third third of the `rand()` range, while the second half of the required range can come only from the second third of the `rand()` range.

What does this mean for you?

Probably nothing. If all you want to do is a dice-roll simulator, you can go without problems with the modulo method, since the range involved is small, and the second problem, despite being *still* present, it's almost irrelevant: suppose your range is 3 and `MAX_RAND` 32767: from 0 to 32765, 0, 1 and 2 has the same probability, but going up to 32767 0 and 1 gain one potential exit, which is almost irrelevant, since they pass from a perfect 1/3 (10922/32766=0,333...) probability for each one to a 10922/32767 for 2 (~0,33332) and 10923/32767 (~0,33335) for 0 and 1 (assuming that `rand()` provides a *perfect* distribution).

Anyhow, to overcome such problems a quite used method is to "stretch" the `rand()` range over a wider range (or compressing it to a smaller range) using a method like this:

```
int GetRandomInt(int Min, int Max)
{
    return (int)(((double)rand())/MAX_RAND*(Max-Min))+Min;
}
```

based on the equivalence `rand():MAX_RAND=X:(Max-Min)`. The conversion to double is necessary, otherwise the integer division between `rand()` and its maximum value will always yield 0 (or 1 in the rare case of `rand()==MAX_RAND`); it could be done in integer arithmetic performing the product first if MAX_RAND is small and the range too is not too wide, otherwise there's a high risk of overflow.

I suspect that, if the output range is bigger than the range of `rand()`, the "stretching" and the fp value truncation (due to the conversion to int) affect in some way the distribution, but just locally (e.g. in small ranges you may never get a certain number, but globally the distribution will look ok).

Notice that this method helps to overcome to a diffused limitation of the C standard library random number generator, i.e. the low randomness of the lower bits of the returned value - which are, incidentally, the ones you are using when you perform a modulo operation with a small output range.

However, keep in mind that the C standard library RNG is a simple one, that strives to comply with "easy" statistical rules, and as such is easily predictable; it shouldn't be used when "serious" random numbers are required (e.g. cryptography). For such needs there are dedicated RNG libraries (e.g. the [RNG part](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Generation.html) of the GNU Scientific Library), or, if you need *really* random stuff, there are several *real* random number services (one of the most famous is [this](http://random.irb.hr/)), which do not use mathematical pseudo-RNG, but take their numbers from real random sources (e.g. radioactive decay).

Comment: thanx...dats exactly wat i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yea, like DarkDust said, this sounds like homework, so, to answer your questions with that in mind, I'd say:

```
--> No, the logic doesnt not change, no matter how many dices you include.

--> Easiest way to do this would be, just make a function that give you ONE
    random function, and depending on how many dices you have, call it that
    many times. 

--> You can instead include for loop in the function and add the values into 
    array and return the array.
```

This way, you can generate random number for 100 dices too.

Answer (score 1):

Since this sounds like homework I'm just going to give hints which should be "good enough" for you (a pro would do it slightly differently): use the `random()` function and the `%` (modulo) operator. Modulo is the "reminder" after a division.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: On POSIX systems there's both: `int rand(void);` and `long random(void);`, both defined in `stdlib.h`. I got no idea about Windows, though.

Comment: As the TS speaks of dice, I'd like to note that using just "modulo" will yield a "loaded dice" due to MAX_RAND being not a multiple of 6. You can overcome this by using "modulo 8" instead of "modulo 6" and discarding numbers >= 6. More details can be found in "The Art of Programming" by Knuth, the chapter on random numbers (I don't remember the exact reference)

Comment: I cheked it, and it's true that it's been defined in stdlib.h, but the *Conforming to* section of their manpages specifies that `rand()` conforms to `SVr4, 4.3BSD, C89, C99, POSIX.1-2001`, while `random()` to `4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001`, so `random` seems to be just UNIX stuff. Nothing bad with it, but since the question was about C in general I thought it was better to use just C standard functions.