# C++ | Generating a pseudo number between 10-20

Tags: c++, random

I am making a text-based C++ RPG and I am trying to figure out how to work out the amount of damage that the enemy hits you for.  My idea is something like this.

Damage done = randomIntBetween10and20*enemyLevel

This way it doesn't always hit for a set amount each time and allows there to be *Critical Strikes* (For example, if the hit is above 15 I would class that as a Critical Strike)

I'm new to C++ so I'm not quite sure how I can do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your problem the generation of random numbers? Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786389/write-a-c-function-that-generates-one-random-number-or-a-pair-of-random-numbers/3786809#3786809

Comment: Is it bad that I first read RPG as Rocket Propelled Grenade?

Comment: @Billy ONeal, it's not bad at all... it's text based.  At the very least the combatant will suffer serious ASCII injuries.

Comment: Did you really mean TRULY? If so, you have to be EXPERIENCED A LOT with C++. Using microphone noise can be profitable :)

Comment: Somebody please edit the title of the question. As plenty of people have pointed out this question has nothing to do with a True Random Number Generator (TRNG).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should omit the word "truly" from the title, because you probably don't mean it. You probably just want a **pseudorandom** number. True randomness is virtually impossible to achieve with a personal computer. The following snippet will give you a pseudorandom number in the range 10..19 inclusive:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

// ...
srand(time(0));
int r = rand() % (20 - 10) + 10;
```

If you want to include 20 in the range then this is a range of 11 numbers:

```
int r = rand() % (21 - 10) + 10
```

Comment: At least this one mentions the difference.  +1

Comment: Quite a few PCs actually have a random input stream based on thermal noise, which includes true randomness.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator

Comment: You have to specifically ask for them though.  The rand() function is pseudo-random.

Comment: don't forget. Only call srand() **once** in an application.

Comment: @Ben: for a suitable definition of "true random", of course. ;)

Comment: @jalf: Thermal noise isn't uncorrelated white gaussian, if that's what you're getting at, but there is some uncorrelated noise mixed in on top of the other stuff.  And I would guess that HW RNG is pretty well equipped to separate that out.

Comment: @Noah: Yes you do need different code.  My comment was directed at wilhelmtell's statement that "True randomness is virtually impossible to achieve with a personal computer", not the code snippet.

Comment: I only have one issue with this snippet: I'm afraid it's biased. If we suppose that `rand()` is unbiaised (to begin with), then `rand() % N` is slightly more likely to yield `0` than to yield `N-1`, unless `N-1` is a divisor of the maximum value that `rand` may generate (or something like that :p). If `N` is small, it's not that noticeable (`1,000,0001` 0 for `1,000,000` 10 for example, would be almost unbiaised), but with N growing the issue is more and more important. I don't know any way to get a uniform distribution in `0..N` in O(1) time though.

Answer (score 7):

A good choice would be `std::random`, the random number generator that’s built-in to C++.

If you don’t have C++11 support yet, use [`boost::random`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_random.html). The new `std::random` is based on `boost::random`, so it’s basically the same thing. The documentation has several examples, including [Generating integers in a range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html#boost_random.tutorial.generating_integers_in_a_range).

One of the options offered is the Mersenne Twister (`mt19937`), which is a good general-purpose pseudo-random number generator.

Like most of the other suggestions, this is pseudo-random. To get true randomness is more difficult—but you don’t need that for an RPG, right? (For cryptographically-strong random numbers, consider [OpenSSL](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers) or, on Windows, [CryptoAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867086.aspx).)

Comment: Well, I'd not call C++0x the "latest version", given that it is not yet C++.

Comment: Meh, it’s close. How about, “upcoming version?” I use `std::random` all the time in MSVC and I know `gcc` 4.5 supports it too.

Answer (score 4):

The stdlib random number generator would be an okay place to start:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

srand(time(NULL)); // initialize the RNG
int poll = rand() % 20; // random number between 0 and 19 inclusive
```

Eventually, you'll want to start using a more random RNG.  *Game Coding Complete* has a pretty decent one to get you started.

Comment: Note that `srand` should be called **ONCE** and never again! (Not every time)

Comment: @Noah:  No RNG is really "truly" random.  All are only psuedo-random.  For what he is asking, either of those options would be "random enough".

Comment: Thankyou, this is just what I need.  Apparently I can't set an accepted answer for another 6 minutes, so I will wait.

Comment: @Zac: Not true. See Noah's answer. Most machines *do* have some system specific ways of getting true random (though not quite as good as something like random.org). For example, `/dev/random` on Linux boxes are generated from such./

Comment: @Billy:  /dev/random and even random.org are only pseudo-random number generators.  If you notice, random.org states that it offers "true" random numbers that are "better" than other psuedo-random number generators.  Better random number generator, sure ... truly random, nope.  But we have gone off on a huge tangent here.

Comment: @Zac: I'm sorry, but you are incorrect. Both the sources I mention are truly random. That's why reading from `/dev/random` is insanely slow, because there's not much randomness to be had on a typical PC, while `/dev/urandom` is fast, because it is pseudorandom.

Comment: @Billy:  Hate to break it to you, but you are incorrect.  There is only 1 known true random number generator "algorithm" (I use the term very loosely there) that we've found so far.  Every other software solution is pseudo-random to varying degrees.  Just because a pseudo-random number generator is better than another, does not make it truly random:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_random_numbers_vs._pseudorandom_numbers

Comment: @Zac: I don't see how that link proves your point. All it says is that a deterministic machine cannot produce true random numbers. Neither `/dev/random` nor random.org are generated via deterministic processes.

Comment: @Zac: The random.org site is not a software solution.

Comment: @Billy: True randomness can not be calculated. So unless a standard PC has a way to measure some physical phenomena (to get the required entropy) that I am unaware of then /dev/random must calculate a randm number and as such is a PRNG and thus not truly random.

Comment: @Zac: AFAIK `/dev/random` picks up entropy from various "casual" hardware stuff (the entropy pool), e.g. from mouse movements, keypress timings, etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#Linux, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_pool#Using_observed_events

Comment: @Martin York: Yes, most PC's don't have many sources of entropy, which is why reading any substantial amount of information from `/dev/random` takes forever. Most PCs do have some limited random generation facilities however, for example, via clock drift or thermal noise.

Comment: @Billy: random.org and [ERNIE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERNIE#ERNIE) use hardware to measure physical phenomena (that apparently are random). You can of course get [appropriate hardware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERNIE#ERNIE) to plug into your PC but it has an associated cost that most people are not willing to pay for (do most people truly need true randomness). So yes PC can generate truly random numbers, but most don't as PC manufacturers are not willing to add to the cost of a PC for something that most people don't care about. /dev/random is slow because it is trying to be good.

Comment: @Billy: If you want to continue this discussion ask the question on SO is "/dev/random" truly random?
"

Comment: @Martin: I don't need to. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#Linux already explains it pretty damn well.

Comment: @Billy: Yes because Wikipedia is a good accurate source of information written by the most knowledgeable people in the field! I love Wikipedia as a starting point for research to find other **authoritative** sources, but as a source it is not a good one (even wikipedias' founder makes this exact statement).

Comment: @Billy: I read the wikipedia page. Which provided [this link](http://everything2.com/title/%252Fdev%252Frandom) in the reference section. That explains that /dev/random uses random noise from the PC to seed the random number generator. SO which do I believe?

Comment: @Martin: If you cannot model it as anything other than random then it is random.

Comment: @Martin: Perhaps more appropriate than an ERNIE link for people who might want to add hardware RNG to a PC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hardware_random_number_generators    And yes, initializing a PRNG with a truly random seed can increase the bitrate without sacrificing (much) randomness.

Comment: @GregS: Yes that is what the crypto world believes. Please feel free to ask the question on SO. See if the majority believe that. @Ben: sure I agree with you it is better than rand() that was not point. @Billy as arguing that /dev/random was truly random. Whoops my second link was supposed to be the one you provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As others said, maybe rand() will be really sufficient for you.
What is important is the seed used to initialise the pseudo random number generator ( the call to srand() is the seed)

But beware, True Chaos doesnt mean that you have exactly the same chance to generate any possible random output.

Ten years ago I have played with stochastic sound generation.
I needed several sources of chaos.

I just let you know those which I had kept and found useful. of course since they need a seed, they are pseudo chaos.

1/for chaotic float number between -1 and 1: compute the function f(x) = cos(exp(x)). exp() grows so fast, that after really few iteration, what goes out from cos() is chaos.

2/the baker transform: chaotic number between 0 and 1: take a number, multiply it by two, and again, when it is superior to 1, substract something so as it goes back betwen 0 and 1. A much more precise explanation [The Baker Transform](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?pid=S0103-97332007000300016&script=sci_arttext).

But I think rand() and srand() will satisfy you.

For applying to your range 10-20, of course you stretch/scale the chaotic range (0;1) or (-1;1) by multiplying and offsetting so as the ouput fits your need. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The method that uses modulus (`%`) isn't a good choice because the distribution is off.  This is better:

```
double GetRandom(double Min, double Max)
{
    return ((double(rand()) / double(RAND_MAX)) * (Max - Min)) + Min;    
}
```

You will need to include `algorithm` and seed the generator with `srand`.

Of course, it's only pseudo-random.  You won't be able to get truly random results, especially with `rand`.

Comment: This looks seriously buggy. Or it is just me? I like where you're going but you're not there yet.

Comment: @GregS What's wrong with it?  I'm willing to fix it, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to 'generate' a truly random number is through the interaction with some environmental factor that is random.  This website provides a service that does that for you: http://www.random.org/

Comment: Glad to see people understanding the difference between true and pseudo random numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

Use srand() to initialise the random number generator:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/

Then use the `rand()` function to generate a sequence of random numbers.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: @Noah Roberts: so, for an RPG do we need to go with crypto-safe RNGs? <_<

Comment: @Noah:  Agreed, but shouldn't one start attacking this with a knife rather than a level 5 battle axe?

Comment: Add srand() for a +1. Not Or sand(). srand() and rand() need to be used together.

Comment: Appreciate your help Martin.  Thank you!  Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0):

look this out, it might be helpful:

```
// random numbers generation in C++ using builtin functions
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <iomanip>

using std::setw;

#include <cstdlib>   // contains function prototype for rand

int main()
{
// loop 20 times
for ( int counter = 1; counter <= 20; counter++ ) {

    // pick random number from 1 to 6 and output it
    cout << setw( 10 ) << ( 1 + rand() % 6 );

    // if counter divisible by 5, begin new line of output
    if ( counter % 5 == 0 )
        cout << endl;

}

return 0;  // indicates successful termination

} // end main
```